# Master Account to Upload Files to sftp Server

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

All,

I'm building an sftp server that will be used for clients to download sensitive information.  Our Medical Records team needs a way to upload the files to the clients home directory.  I'm thinking Filezilla or WinSCP, but I need a master account that they can use.  The account just needs permissions to upload the files.  Any thoughts?

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04

Thanks!!